# When access API, getting 500 Internal Server Error. After successfully login from Identity Server4 Login form and redirecting to Anglar front-end

Tags: identityserver4

I am using Angular front-end, .netcore API and identityserver4. 
I am testing AddSigningCredential(certificate) for both development environment and production environment. Working fine in my local, after successfully login from identityserver4 login, redirecting from identityserver4 login to font-end angular, can generate access token and can access API data too.

But for my production deployment, although can generate access token using AddSigningCredential(certificate), getting 500 internal server error when access API. Am I missing something? and Please advise. Thanks.

I create Self-Sign Certificate in IIS and export it with private key and then import in Personal store.

Search and pass this certificate as parameter in AddSigningCredential() for deployment
In my identityserver4 Startup.cs file ,

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
             .Build();

            string identityServerUrl = config.GetSection("UrlSetting").GetValue<string>("IdentityServerUrl");
            string sslCertificateThumbprint = config.GetSection("UrlSetting").GetValue<string>("SSLCertificateThumbprint");
            string sslCertificateSerialNumber = config.GetSection("UrlSetting").GetValue<string>("SSLCertificateSerialNumber");
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
            }
            else
            {
                X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, sslCertificateThumbprint, false);
                if (certCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    builder.AddSigningCredential(certCollection[0]);
                }
            }
```

my access token value and token info:

```
access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjkxRUYzODkwMkNBNDE0QTRBOThCMjNGNEZBM0VFRjZFMkJCNkE5NUMiLCJ0eXAiOiJhdCtqd3QiLCJ4NXQiOiJrZTg0a0N5a0ZLU3BpeVAwLWo3dmJpdTJxVncifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1ODA4Nzg3OTQsImV4cCI6MTU4MDg4NTk5NCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly8xMC4xLjE0MS4xNi9tYWNpZGVudGl0eSIsImF1ZCI6Im1hY2FwaSIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Im5nIiwic3ViIjoiNTk5Njk2M2EtZTA5Ni00MjE1LThjMzgtODA1Y2Y0OTZiOThlIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTgwODc4Nzk0LCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsIkFzcE5ldC5JZGVudGl0eS5TZWN1cml0eVN0YW1wIjoiSkFDWUtMSzZSMlhVUlQyTk1TUlVBSUlRNjdHT1dWQzUiLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsInNjb3BlIjpbIm9wZW5pZCIsInByb2ZpbGUiLCJlbWFpbCIsIm1hY2FwaSJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl19.c-0sjA4k5kJZXTMhTgH_Mo0S5X9JVdCfk2D3FpK4aAQ7I4ej6p1pI1q-ybhyLYO_sNdMDhWpd6_xulpdRhnTOjQauhGjcno3h-Wanm8LHn6Nhl3m_0VqjBK96c5gEZRJI_qstCKFISL9YWMhPAEXc_YusDtq7vFZZGnx1zdD7sER3YHBuvpLreTRScOzWuhIEE4RTLipmyvyAqrvbAYWwQ5M_u8EjB2lvP5MnhHY9RAr1LqnjOeiKffGMe7RcUaoZDnQcCVT-38hYfZxS9ETcKYDTT_C-CXvOUyGV9EwGJSDbxqHvZcjZ4grPmVU5-lKK8QkQPHjgQagzWHRhhDknA&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=7200&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20testapi&state=8g8QZfc4rnJBoUeSvMEjU6DwY3dASb7Yp9uJGpOe&session_state=1trGZTtEqsh9pqPlPDNYFEIvDhilDrvibON6V11yGok.KJVy1w-xkxw9iRtT-bh9Ag'
```

API is protected using identityserver4 and using angular-oauth2-oidc for connecting angular and identity server, grant-type is implicit.

I have tested both AddDeveloeprSigningCredential() and AddSigningCredential() in my local.
I think working fine when I run with source code, such as If I haven't passed access token value from front-end angular app to backend api, I am getting HttpResponseStatusCode 401 and cannot retrieve my API data.

If I passed access token value from front-end angular to backend api, I can retrieve my API data without getting any error.

For deployment, When I check my serverside log,

```
2020-02-05 08:21:39 10.1.121.11 GET /webapi/api/student/availablestudent type=P1&nrcno=&filtertype=S 443 - 10.1.121.11 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.130+Safari/537.36 https://10.1.121.11/TrainingManagementSystem/trainingmanagementsystem/person/search 500 0 0 49
```

Comment: 500 is a server error, check the server side log for more details.

Comment: @MattClark , I added my server log in my question post. Can you please help to check what is the root cause. Thank you.

Comment: The serverside logs are more useful, can you add that to the question? And please remove the (link to) images and paste the text instead. And an image of an (partial) acces token isn't helpful at all. Instead add the (complete) token as text, unless it can be used for a public site.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg, I added my server log message to the question.